# What do && , === mean in one line?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the following JavaScript

```
this.Var1 && Obj1.Var1 && (Obj1.Var2 = this.Obj1.Func1(Obj1.Var1), Obj1.Var3 = this.Obj1.Func2(Obj1.Var1), this.Func1(Obj1.Var1)), Obj1.Var4 === "String1" && (Obj1.Var5 = Func1(Obj1.Var5)), this.Func2(Obj1) && this.Func3("String2").pushObject(Obj1), x = this.get("String2.length"), o = x - y;
```

I get this line of code from a minified JavaScript file,

but I think hard to understand

What do those `&&` `,` `===` mean in this line of JavaScript?

How can I make this line more readable?

Comment: They mean pretty much the same thing they do as when an expression is spread over more than one line. Reading minified JavaScript is always going to be painful. You can use http://jsbeautifier.org to make it look a little better.

Comment: You may want to start with non-minified code

Comment: try Google search "javascript &&" then "javascript ===" there are lots off excellent definitions to be found. Try some bsic javascript tutorials or primers first.

Comment: how much javascript do you know?

Comment: I've tried using jsbeautifier.org.
but it would only do line breaks, add spaces and something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we format the code better to understand it:

```
this.Var1 && Obj1.Var1 && (
    Obj1.Var2 = this.Obj1.Func1(Obj1.Var1),
    Obj1.Var3 = this.Obj1.Func2(Obj1.Var1),
    this.Func1(Obj1.Var1)
),
(Obj1.Var4 === "String1") && (Obj1.Var5 = Func1(Obj1.Var5)),
this.Func2(Obj1) && this.Func3("String2").pushObject(Obj1),
x = this.get("String2.length"),
o = x - y;
```

You may not be aware of:

- [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation):

  > `falsy && anything` is short-circuit evaluated to `falsy`.
  >   `truly || anything` is short-circuit evaluated to `truly`.
  >
  > The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always
  >   correct. Note that the `anything` part of the above expressions is not
  >   evaluated, so any side effects of doing so do not take effect.
- [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Comma_operator)

  > The comma operator allows multiple expressions to be evaluated in a
  >   single statement and returns the result of the last expression.

Then, the code is equivalent to

```
if (this.Var1) {
    if (Obj1.Var1) {
        Obj1.Var2 = this.Obj1.Func1(Obj1.Var1);
        Obj1.Var3 = this.Obj1.Func2(Obj1.Var1);
        this.Func1(Obj1.Var1);
    }
}
if (Obj1.Var4 === "String1") {
    Obj1.Var5 = Func1(Obj1.Var5);
}
if (this.Func2(Obj1)) {
    this.Func3("String2").pushObject(Obj1);
}
x = this.get("String2.length");
o = x - y;
```

Comment: This means the `,` is to join multiple if statements into one single line by replacing the `{}` with `()`?

Comment: and `foo && (bar)` is always equivalent to `if(foo) {bar}`?

Comment: `foo && (bar)` is equivalent to `(function(){ var value; if(value = foo){ value = bar; } return value;})()`. However, if you don't care about the returned value, it's like `if(foo){ bar; }`

Comment: No, `,` doesn't join if statements. It joins expressions, and returns the result of the last one.

Comment: Like `return` statement? If yes, return for what? The function?

Comment: @WhyCode No, it doesn't exit the function, but it gives you a value (like when calling a function): `1 && 2` is `2`, `0 && 1` is `0`

Answer (score 3):

`&&` is the logical and operator and

`===` is a strict equality comparison that compares both type and value.

Comment: what do they mean when they appear in the same line multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

For the commas, you can declare multiple variables in a single line by using them:

```
var x = 1, y = 2;
```

Logical and operators keep line of code going. So if you have:

```
x == 1 && callMethod()
```

callMethod is only invoked if x is equal to 1. Triple equals typically checks object type as well. So:

```
x == "1"
```

Is true

```
x === "1"
```

is false.

Comment: Does `x == 1 && callMethod()` mean `if(x==1) callMethod()` ?